# What app could open text from anywhere in the editor of your choice?

Tags: macos, software

On my previous installation, I had a small tool that took text from e.g. a web form after pressing e.g. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, pasted it in the editor of my choice where I would edit it. After saving, it was pasted back to the original place. The app was on the App Store in its early days, later pulled and still available from GitHub.

I can't remember its name, can you?

Thanks.

Comment: If you download from App Store, you should try to open the app and go to Purchased tab. Should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jherran’s comment I found the app: *QuickCursor* from Hog Bay Software ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/jessegrosjean/quickcursor)).